# How to make a pointer to a varible inside nested structs in C?

Tags: c

In the following code,how to create a pointer to the variable ***triangle.pluto.mars.a*** so it becomes unnecessary in the printf line to repeat the whole path for member ***a***.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    struct euler {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    struct gauss {
        int f;
        int g;
        struct euler mars;

    };

    struct aristotle{
        int x;
        int y;
        struct gauss pluto;
    } triangle;

    triangle.pluto.mars.a = 151;

    printf("\nThe value is: %d\n\n",triangle.pluto.mars.a );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using the `&` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The band-aid solution:

```
int * someVariable = &(triangle.pluto.mars.a);
```

The long solution: Do a redesign.

Comment: Is it possible to make a pointer that points to ***triangle.pluto.mars*** and let's me allow it as in ***(*pointer_to_mars).a*** or ***(*pointer_to_mars).b*** ?

Comment: Yes....the code I posted above creates a pointer that points to triangle.pluto.mars

Comment: Yes, but I mean a pointer that allows me to access every member of ***mars*** rather than one pointer for ***mars.a***, another pointer for ***mars.b*** and so on.

Comment: Then you will have to create a pointer to `struct euler`. Like `struct euler* p=&triangle.pluto.mars;`

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted @EugeneSh. I was previously trying to create a pointer of type ***struct aristotle***, but now I understand one must create a pointer to the type which is last in the chain  rather than the first struct(or so it seems), ***struct euler*** in this case.

Comment: To be more precise, the type of the pointer should be that it is pointing to. In other words the type of the field it is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to rearrange your structures, you will have a more "intuitive" means of accessing your members. While C does not offer inheritance, it does guarantee that the pointer to the first member of a structure is equal in value to the pointer to the containing structure. This allows you to mimic inheritance like behavior via pointer conversion.

```
    struct euler {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    struct gauss {
        struct euler mars;
        int f;
        int g;    
    };

    struct aristotle{
        struct gauss pluto;
        int x;
        int y;
    } triangle;

    triangle.pluto.mars.a = 151;

    struct euler *e = (void *)&triangle;
    struct gauss *g = (void *)&triangle;

    printf("\nThe value is: %d\n\n", e->a );
```

This guarantee is stated in C.11 §6.7.2.1 ¶15 (emphasis mine, and similar language exists in C.99):

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.** There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

This does not take away from [@LawrenceAiello's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31416763/315052), which still works after the reorganization suggested above.

Comment: Don't know why your answer got downvoted. Actually it is an interesting observation and in fact it works. What is the point of ***(void *)*** in this case? I just wrote the code you suggested without the  ***(void *)*** part and it seems to work.

Comment: If full diagnostics are enabled, you are technically assigning to a pointer variable from an incompatible type. The cast suppresses that diagnostic, since the code is perfectly legal, per the C standard I cited. As to the downvotes, while this code is legal, it is easy to abuse `void *` casts. So the downvotes are to warn you away from it.

Comment: Rely on structure layout and use casting, just to avoid a bit of typing? I can't vote for this. I'm not even sure the cast is strictly guaranteed to work , the standard only clearly says that a pointer converted to `void *` can be converted back to what it originally came from.

Comment: Not that it even avoids typing; `(void *)&triangle` is longer than `&triangle.pluto`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It is not to avoid typing, but to provide a consistent programming idiom. What you say about `void *` is true if you do not believe conversion is transitive.

Answer (score -3):

```
int *num = &(triangle.pluto.mars.a);
```

I suggest you redesign your structs fields to be pointers.

Such as

```
struct euler {
    int *a;
    int *b;
};
```

Comment: Why should it be redesigned this way? How would the values be assigned?

Comment: Pointers are variables which store the address of other things in C. 

A basic example would be:
int num = 5;
int *numPointer = &num;

Now numPointer stores the address location of num.

If you change numPointer = something. You will change where numPointer is pointing to and lose num.

Comment: So how would it help in this case?

Comment: I suggest you read more on pointers and a function called malloc() after you master pointers. So in your example after modifying with my answer above you can do:

int *num = triangle.pluto.mars.a;

printf("\nThe value is: %d\n\n", *num);

*num deferences the pointer variable num so you can access where its pointing to.

Comment: @Juan that's no different to the current top-voted solution, except that your code has to use a whole lot of extra malloc and free calls.